# How to keep kern.log out of syslog

Tags: logs, rsyslog, syslog

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and I found that I could get the log of kernel from two places: `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. `/var/log/syslog` contains other logs but I could find `/var/log/kern.log` in it.

So it is possible to keep the `kern.log` out of the `syslog`? I mean I want to remove the `kern.log` from the `syslog`?

I've tried to remove the `module(load="imklog")` from the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` but this will remove all of kernel log from the `kern.log` and the `syslog`, whereas what I need is not to touch the `kern.log`, only to remove the kernel log from the `syslog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04, your `rsyslog` rules would be found in the `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file. Inside that file, you'll see the two following lines:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
kern.*                      -/var/log/kern.log
```

You could skip the kernel messages from being logged to `/var/log/syslog` like so:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv,kern.none     -/var/log/syslog
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
```